# How to feeding hidden state vectors from one transformer directly into a layer of different transformer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

The transformer models take as input token Ids, which are converted into embeddings. I am wondering how to input embeddings directly.

I am asking for both the Pytorch and Keras versions of the models.

Comment: Are you talking about BERT? Random embeddings won't work well if you feed them directly into the Encoder. What is your need? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @WasiAhmad I am looking to feed embeddings from one transformer to another. I was originally looking to use Roberta-base models in my architecture but for some reason I am getting an OOM error (though training one large model seems to work fine). So now I am looking to use just one roberta-base model, and then two separate models, each containing the last two layers of roberta-base.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is because the layers of these models mimic low-dimension spaces, so just feeding one layer's output to another breaking the pipeline doesn't make any sense. Programmatically you can do that you want but first, think how embedding can be directly fed into the last two layers of another copy of the model.